# facebook deleted my apps with pending balance of nine thousands usd

Tags: facebook

i was using my facebook app only facebook instant article purpose. i never used this app for any other reason.to days ago i have only added one of my friends as administrator to the app.and  facebook deleted my apps as well the facebook Id with pending of 9 thousands USD.

Comment: What has this got to do with SO?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with coding

Comment: Either it happened as you said. Or the friend was perhaps not really one. Anyway: https://developers.facebook.com/appeal

Comment: facebook has give me an option to appeal.aleady appealed.so it is not my friend who may remove me.and i am new here,sorry if i make mistake to choose catagory.

Comment: @CBroe i am feeling tension for my pending balance. will i get it or lost